# Rails Migration File not adding columns to Mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a login system in Rails, but, when I go to the signup page, I get an error saying : "undefined method `first_name' for #". I checked my users database for the "first_name" column, and found that the only columns in the "users" table were "id", "created_at", and "updated_at". I created my app using rails new appname -d mysql, I have the mysql2 gem, I have updated my databases.yml file, and I have run "rake db:migrate". Still, nothing works. How can I fix this? This is my users controller:

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create 
    @user = User.new(user_params) 
  if @user.save 
    session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    redirect_to '/login' 
  else 
    redirect_to '/signup' 
  end 
end
  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
  end
end
```

Here is my router:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'main#index'
    get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
    get '/signup' => 'users#new'
    resources :users
    post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Here is my model:

```
   class User < ApplicationRecord
        has_secure_password
    end
```

Here is my Migration file:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="login">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form">

    <h1>Sign up</h1>

    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last name" %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>
      <%= f.submit "Create an account", class: "btn-submit" %>
    <% end %>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using Rails 5.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: can you try to remigrate(db:migrate:redo) the last migration

Comment: I tried that and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to redo the migration with db:migrate:redo, if that doesnt work, create a new migration adding the respective columns.

```
  class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
     def change
        add_column :products, :part_number, :string
        add_column :products, :price, :decimal
     end
  end
```